# Node modules don't apply css

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I'm new to React development and I try to use webpack to set up my project. Unfortunately, I have a problem with my configuration: with it, components from node_modules don't apply styles no matter if I try to build the application or to start it with webpack-dev-server.

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/i,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: 'css-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|ttf|svg)/i,
                use: 'file-loader'
            },
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 9000,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
}
```

**.babelrc**:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**UPD:** I didn't mean the styles I wrote, but the styles of the components themselves. For example, Button component of the [primereact](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/) renders like the default html button.

Comment: `components from node_modules don't apply styles...` are you importing the styles into your components?

Comment: Did you declare the style file in the beginning of every component model?

Comment: I didn't mean the styles I wrote, but the styles of the components themselves. For example, Button component of the primereact renders like the default html <button>.

Comment: @VladislavMaksimov I mean the styles which are with the module - not your own

Comment: @StudioTime I think the code like ```var _style = _interopRequireDefault(require("./style.css"));``` inside the components of the modules which I want to use should import all the styles.  
  
Is it all ok with my config? I can avoid this problem by using create-react-app but I still want to understand what the problem is.